# Where can I find more information about FullStack Flux

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtmjkCuV-EU) the author explains how he implemented fullstack flux for his application. I cannot find any information about this topic on google. i'd like to learn more about this. Any suggestions?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. How would you suggest rephrasing that so that it's more clear?

Comment: In the video Pete Hunt talks about implementing reactjs + flux + backend (server-side). Google "react flux backend" or "react flux isomorphic" to find more info on the topic.